# Does a solution exist for $u_x u_{xx} = 1- x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find a solution to the equation

$$\det(T(x))g(\nabla T(x)) = f(x)$$

where $T(x)$ has the form $T(x) = \nabla \phi$, $f(x) = 1-x$ and $g(x) = x$.

I think this leads to

$$\phi_x \phi_{xx} = 1 - x,$$

but I'm unsure if there's a solution. I tried $\phi = Ax^2 + Bx$ to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integrating gives
$$ 2\phi_x \phi_{xx} = 2(1-x) $$
$$ {\phi_x}^2 = C - (1-x)^2 $$

$$ \phi_x = \pm \sqrt{C-(1-x)^2} $$

You can do the rest.

Comment: How do you do the integration - by parts?

Comment: Also, is my reasoning of going from the first equation to the one I solved valid? Many thanks!

Comment: @MichaelSnow You can easily integrate the right hand side. To see how the left hand side integrates, just apply the chain rule or product rule of differentiation to $\phi_x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\phi_x \phi_{xx} = (1 - x)$$
Substitute $p=\phi_x$
$$pp_x = 1 - x,$$
$$pdp =\int  (1 - x) dx$$
$$p^2 =2\int  (1 - x) dx$$
$$p^2 =2 (x - \frac {x^2}2+K)$$
$$p^2 =2 x -  {x^2}+K$$
$$\phi_x =\pm\sqrt{2 x -  {x^2}+K}$$

Is $\phi_x$ a partial derivative ?